# Unable to print a perticular name in selenium webdriver using java

Tags: java, html, selenium

My Java

```
package com.ej.zob.modules;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Manage_Branch {
public void Execute(String IFSC)
{
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText("MANAGE")).click();
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText("BRANCH")).click();
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td/div[text()='"+IFSC+"']"));
    WebElement col = LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[count(//table/thead/tr/th[.='BRANCH NAME']/preceding-sibling::th)+4]"));

    if(IFSC.equalsIgnoreCase(IFSC))
    {
        System.out.println(col.getText());

    }
}
```

}

My HTML

```
<table id="flex1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<thead>
<tr class="hDiv">
<th width="6%">
<div class="text-left field-sorting asc" rel="IFSC_CODE"> IFSC CODE </div>
</th>
<th width="6%">
<div class="text-left field-sorting " rel="BRANCH_NAME"> BRANCH NAME </div>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="sorted" width="6%">
<div class="text-left">SACS011151</div>
</td>
<td width="6%">
<div class="text-left">check</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="erow">
<td class="sorted" width="6%">
<div class="text-left">SACS011152</div>
</td>
<td width="6%">
<div class="text-left">Motiram</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="erow">
<td class="sorted" width="6%">
<div class="text-left">SACS011158</div>
</td>
<td width="6%">
<div class="text-left">TESTNAME</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to print value from column name "BRANCH NAME" say "check" but when user passes value of IFSC CODE say "SACS011151" then the value in front of that particular IFSC CODE should be printed.But in my case it is printing the value from 8th row only whatever the IFSC code you pass it is only taking "TESTNAME". For help you can see the above image for better understanding.I don't know why it is happening. Hope you understand Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
WebElement col = LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//thead//div[text()='+"IFSC"+']//../following-sibling::td/div"));

Comment: this should work, just one point if you are having multiple columns then select appropriate column by providing index like $x('//tbody/tr/td/div[text()='+"IFSC"+']/../following-sibling::td[1]/div')

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement col = LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.tagName('tbody')).findElement(By.tagName('tr')).findElements(By.tagName('td'))[1]
```

Comment: Now it is printing IFSC VALUE "SACS011158" but what I need is values under BRANCH NAME column.User will pass IFSC value.

Comment: No the above line is not correct.Because if you use findElements then it will require List<WebElement>. Also I doubt about the position of [1]

Answer (score 0):

Once try this:

```
   WebElement col = LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div[text()='SACS011151']"));

if(col.equals("SACS011151")){
     WebElement branchNameEle = LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[4]"));
     System.out.println("BranchName: "+branchNameEle.getText());
}
```

Comment: Well but this is not my requirement.

Comment: Then what is your requirement??

Comment: user will pass value of IFSC CODE  and value under BRANCH NAME should be printed. If I pass IFSC CODE value "SACS011151" then the value under BRANCH NAME "check" should be printed. see above image for ref.

Comment: I have edited my code. once try that. Actually we will the text of same row and we have to check that passing value is same as getting value or not. If that is same then you can change the last tag in xpath ' td[1]' to td[4]. td[4] means that value 4 refer the column number in your table.